# How to make windows fax work in virtual windows xp mode?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, virtualization, fax

Here is back story:  We are updating all our users to Windows 7 and we use an ancient database system called piclan that will only run in windows xp because it relies on the ipx protocol. Pic outputs order confirmations that need to be faxed to end users. Since Pic is in the virtual world it attempts to use it's own virtual windows xp fax instead of the windows 7 fax.  (Windows 7 fax works).

To make virtual fax work this is what I've tried so far:

I've added virtual user to our domain, gave virtual user printer fax privileges.

I can see fax in printers and devices.

Under tools->fax printer status it says "%servername% connection error".

If I go to "Send fax" I have two options, "%servername%/fax" and "%servername%/fax on my pc".

I've tried both and the fax was never received.

Virtual xp config info:

- intel 82578dc gigabit network connection option tested
- shared network network connection option tested
- Up to date with the latest windows patches (SP3).
- Windows firewall is disabled.

Comment: Questions: (1) Are you running Windows XP under Virtual PC (XP Mode), or are you using a third-party hypervisor? (2) Does the fax device connect to your computer using USB, or does it connect to the network using Ethernet? (3) What physical device is `%servername%`? Is it the Windows 7 host, the fax printer hardware, or an actual Windows server that provides print services for your network? (4) Do you literally see `%servername%` on your screen, or do you see the actual name of the server?

Comment: @Miles We have the capability to email confirmations but several companies we deal with still require fax confirmations. I would love to ditch fax, but it's just not possible atm.

Comment: (1)Windows XP under Virtual PC (XP Mode)
(2)Network - Our windows server hosts the printer / fax drivers
(3)Servername is our windows server
(4)No, actual servername. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

What networking mode are the Windows VMs running in?  Bridged, Private, Shared?  Check that it's in Bridged Mode, and that you can ping and/or RDP to the XP VM.  That would be my first step.

Comment: I have it set to the network connection on my pc. (intel 82578dc gigabit network connection). I verified that I can remote into the virtual mode from my pc.

Comment: I should mention there is n bridged or private options... Just "Not Connected", "Internal Network", "Shared Networking (NAT)" and "Intel(R) 82578DC Gigabit Network Connection". I'm using the last option.

Comment: If you have selected the name of the network adapter ("Intel..."), that is the correct option. You are in Bridged mode.

Comment: Can you ping the %servername from the VMs?  Are the VMs members of the domain?

Comment: Yep, pinging the server from the Virtual machine works. The VMs ARE members of the domain.

Comment: Have you tried disabling Integration Services?

Comment: I just tried disabling integration services, no joy. I removed fax and re-added fax. Under printers and faxes the fax is still "ready" but when I go to fax console the fax printers status says Connection error. I also verified that i can still ping the printer server.